# AWS RDS Table Read slow even with index

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, indexing

I am very new to AWS.

I have two servers. One is my site server (which is located in my company not my computer, I will call it **server A**) and another one is on **AWS**. I am migrating tables from site server to AWS server.

My problem is table read is slow for AWS server. I am not sure if the latency is coming from DB part or could be solved from AWS setting (if there is something I can do here).

The server A is based on MySQL (not sure about version) and AWS is based on Aurora.

My query is this:

```
SELECT sessionId, sequence, timestamp, source, sourceType, repId, 
   content, contentType FROM chatLines 
   WHERE sessionId=%s ORDER BY sequence ASC;
```

I tried to find if this is index problem, but the index information is same with server A and AWS server as follows:

```
Table, Non_unique, Key_name, Seq_in_index, Column_name, Collation, Cardinality, Index_type

chatLines,  0,  PRIMARY,    1,  id, A,  2492436 ,           BTREE       
chatLines,  0,  IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_SEQUENCE,   1,  sessionId,  A,  166162,             BTREE       
chatLines   0   IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_SEQUENCE    2   sequence    A   2492436             BTREE       
chatLines   1   IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_TIMESTAMP   1   sessionId   A   166162              BTREE       
chatLines   1   IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_TIMESTAMP   2   timestamp   A   2492436             BTREE       
chatLines   1   IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_BYTYPE  1   sessionId   A   207703              BTREE       
chatLines   1   IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_BYTYPE  2   sourceType  A   623109              BTREE
```

Here is the table schema that I used to create table. I got this from MySQL Workbench -> import schema

```
-- Table structure for table `chatLines`
--

/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `chatLines` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`sessionId` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`sequence` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
`timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
`source` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`sourceType` char(1) NOT NULL,
`repId` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`content` mediumtext,
`contentType` char(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_SEQUENCE` (`sessionId`,`sequence`),
KEY `IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_TIMESTAMP` (`sessionId`,`timestamp`),
KEY `IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_BYTYPE` (`sessionId`,`sourceType`),
CONSTRAINT `chatLines_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sessionId`) 
  REFERENCES `chatSessions` (`sessionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=308232770 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Here is EXPLAIN Select result:

```
explain select * from chatLines 
where sessionId = 'ID1560302010' order by sequence asc

1. Server A

id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, SIMPLE, chatLines, ref, IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_SEQUENCE,IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_TIMESTAMP,IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_BYTYPE, IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_SEQUENCE, 62, const, 16, Using where

2. AWS

id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, SIMPLE, chatLines, ref, IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_SEQUENCE,IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_TIMESTAMP,IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_BYTYPE, IDX_CHATLINES_SESSIONID_SEQUENCE, 62, const, 16,**Using index condition;** Using where
```

Here is AWS parameter (which I think it is important) configuration. Please note that "SELECT" is slow for AWS:

1. query_cache_size:    {DBInstanceClassMemory/24}
2. query_cache_type: 1
3. innodb_buffer_pool_size: {DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4}
4. switch innodb_adaptive_hash_index = 1

Comment: What is the schema like? Edit the question to add `SHOW CREATE TABLE chatLines`.

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer the question that was asked. (Was there a question asked?)  There's no mention of the sizing of the EC2 instance, the storage engine for the `chatlines` table (InnoDB or MyISAM), what version of MySQL you're running, etc. We're just guessing that you've got MySQL Community Edition installed on Linux. And we don't know how you are measuring/determining that "table read is slow". I understand you have a performance problem, but the way this "question" is presented, there isn't any way to answer it.

Comment: Also post the result of your `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. To paraphrase @spencer7593 and toward diagnosis: storage engine = InnoDB ✔. MySQL version = ? EC2 instance size = ? Number of rows in table = ?

Comment: Also, could you please try the query without the ORDER BY and tell me if that helps performance?

Comment: The row size is about 3,000,000. I tried it without ORDER BY, but it does not help performance. I just printed timestamp on python and checked the time difference.

Comment: Sorry, I am not quite sure about AWS service. I am just checking 'RDS Dashboard" to check the DB instance. If there is any menu that I can check AWS setting (in terms of RDB), please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that you are using Amazon RDS service, and not MySQL installed on an EC2 instance. If your Python code is running a local server, and you are connecting to AWS, that's going to be additional time, and that could be considerable, especially if you are transferring a large amount of data "across the wire". As a quick test, you could add "LIMIT 1" to the query. That would reduce the amount of data that is transferred. See if it is as "slow" returning one row as it is the whole set.

Comment: Sorry for the misclassification.  The server is not local server. So, I am connecting two remote servers. And I cannot use LIMIT 1, because there are many rows that share same "sessionId" with difference "sequence".

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `id` and the current `PRIMARY KEY`.  Change the unique index to be

```
PRIMARY KEY(`sessionId`,`sequence`)
```

After that change, the query in question will run faster (on any machine), and probably most other queries will run faster.

This change will also eliminate a problem you may be headed for:  `id` has a limit of about 2 billion and you are already at 0.3 billion.

As for why the two servers perform differently, they are apparently running different version of MySQL.  Which versions?

Let's check something else, too.  How much RAM on each?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
It seems obvious that it is AWS setting issue. I made local db on my machine, and my local is fast like the other server.
The aws setting (which I think this may important) from RDS is as follows:
innodb_buffer_pool_size: {DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4}
query_cache_size: {DBInstanceClassMemory/24}
query_cache_type: 1
Please let me know if there is any other important parameter I have to take care.

Comment: 3/4 sounds good.  The query_cache settings are unlikely to affect _this_ question.  However, I advise that `query_cache_size` be no more than 50M.

Comment: Different amounts of RAM?  Different disk system (SSD vs spinning, etc)?

Comment: Is the table InnoDB on both servers?

Comment: The Version is important because `Using index condition` is a relatively new feature.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html

Comment: I believe that the both (AWS and server) are innoDB. Not quite sure about server's MySQL version. But my local MySQL is 5.7 and it is fast.

Comment: Not sure if this is ongoing issue with Aurora. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=711589

Comment: Keep in mind that some Clouds do not have the disk on the server, but have it 'across the network'.  This can be costly for table scans.

Comment: And it sounds like you are shoveling 50MB from the disk to the client.

Comment: So there is no issue with my parameter setting except query_cache_size?

Comment: Let's say "no obvious issues".  If you want more thorough analysis, provide `SHOW VARIABLES`, `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` and ram size.  (Probably need `post.it`, or something, because of size.)  The defaults are pretty good; your usage may indicate the need to deviate from defaults.